# Como posicionar o placeholder

Tags: html5, css3, placeholder

Como posso posicionar o *placeholder*? Criei um `input` mas o campo digitável não acompanha, como na imagem de exemplo:

[image: Espaço onde quro remover]

```css
.inpt {
    border: none;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    padding: 3% 20%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
    <input name="nome" type="text" class="inpt" placeholder="Nome">
</form>
```

Comment: você quer remover esse espaço que marcou em vermelho? não entendi muito bem sua pergunta...

Comment: Sim quero remove-lo

Comment: Seu input está com padding de 20% nas laterais. Tire ele.

Comment: @DaviAragao poste como resposta, mesmo resolvendo no comentário é legal registrar a sua resposta!

Comment: @hugocsl fique a vontade.

Comment: @DaviAragao seu mérito jovem, respondei ai, se não a pergunta vai ficar aberta sem resposta, ai fica aparecendo na lista de perguntas sem resposta, mesmo já tendo sido resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se bem entendi, você quer remover o espaço, mas manter o placeholder no centro, certo?! Como o pessoal falou, o espaço é causado pelo seu `padding`, basta tirar ele.
Mas se quiser manter o `placeholder` no centro, pode utilizar apenas um `text-align: center`, assim:

```html
<input type='text' placeholder="Nome" style="text-align: center" />
```

No entanto, note que mesmo o texto normal ficou alinhado ao centro. Isso podemos resolver com um pouquinho de JavaScript, assim:

```js
// Quando a tela estiver carregada...
window.onload = function() {
  // Reconhece cada input na tela
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // Aqui fazemos um loop passando por todos os inputs
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // Essa linha é pra chamar a função em cada um dos inputs quando a tela for carregada
    mudarPlaceholder(inputs[i]);
    // Aqui falamos que pra cada tecla que o usuário apertar no input
    inputs[i].setAttribute('onkeyup', 'mudarPlaceholder(this)');
  }
};

// Função para mudar a centralização
function mudarPlaceholder(that) {
  // Se o input estiver vazio
  if (that.value === '') {
    // Tira a classe normal
    that.classList.remove('normal');
    // Centraliza o placeholder
    that.classList.add('centralizado');
  } else {
    // Senão, tira o centralizado do input
    that.classList.remove('centralizado');
    that.classList.add('normal');
  }
}
```

```css
.centralizado {
  text-align: center;
}

.normal {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Nome" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Um `ìnput` do tipo texto não tem espaço nas laterais entre o seu conteúdo e a borda.

Esse comportamento é resultado de `padding: 3% 20%`, que está "estufando" o seu elemento em 3% para `top` e `bottom` e 20% para `left` e `right`.

Retire o padding ou ajuste-o para outro valor.
Os guide lines do [material design](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#spec) indicam 12dps para esse espaçamento.

```css
.inpt {
    border: none;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    padding: 12px 16px 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input name="nome" type="text" class="inpt" placeholder="Nome">
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá?
Se compreendi corretamente, voce esta querendo deixar o placeholder centralizado, certo?
Primeiramente retire o padding que voce colocou ( padding: 3% 20%;), depois basta adiconar a propriedade e valor á seguir na estilização do seu input: text-align: center;

Espero ter ajudado!!!